# Canvas: ¿Como guardar,cargar y editar Canvas desde un formulario en PHP, Javascript y Mysqli?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, canvas

Buen día, quisiera me ayuden con esta inquietud. Agregué al formulario de artículos un canvas de tal forma que el usuario pueda dibujar dentro de este elemento. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero quisiera saber como almacenar ese canvas, no se si en una base de datos o dentro de un directorio del servidor, de tal forma que cuando se cargue la información del producto se pueda volver editar o modificar el dibujo.Estoy trabajando con PHP y MySQli. Gracias